Explanation on the proof of Takesaki's Proposition V.2.10
I am stuck on the proof of the following Proposition V.2.10 of Takesaki's Vol 1:

Proposition 2.10. If $\tau$ is a semifinite normal trace on a von Neumann algebra $\mathscr{M}$, then there exists a unique central projection $z\in \mathscr{M}$ such that $\tau =0$ on $\mathscr{M}_+(1-z)$ and $\tau$ is faithful on $\mathscr{M}z$.

Proof. First note that the set $\{e:\tau(e)=0\}$ is an upward directed set of projections. Denote $p:=\vee \{e:\tau(e)=0\}$. Then $\tau(p)=0$. After that the author mentioned that

Since $\tau(upu^*)=\tau(p)=0$ for all unitary $u$, we have $upu^*=p$ for all unitary $u$.

I didn't get how exactly this follows?
On the next line they wrote:

It follows, from the spectral decomposition theorem, that $\tau =0$ on $\mathscr{M}_+p$ and $\tau$ is faithful on $\mathscr{M}(1-p)$.

How exactly the spectral theorem used there? Also $\tau:\mathscr{M}_+\to [0. \infty]$, then how $\tau$ is defined on $\mathscr{M}(1-p)$?
Thank you.
EDIT If $x\in \mathscr{M}_+$ and $x \le 1$, then we get $xp \le p$. Hence $\tau(xp) \le \tau(p)=0$. In the general case we can use this argument on $x/\|x\|$ to conclude $\tau(xp) =0$. Thus I got $\tau$ is zero on $\mathscr{M}_+p$.

For the first question, the point is that $\tau(upu^\ast) = 0$, so by definition $upu^\ast \in \{e: \tau(e) = 0\}$. As $e$ is the supremum of the latter set, $upu^\ast \leq p$. But this holds for all unitary $u$, so in particular, if we apply the above to $u^\ast$ instead of $u$, we obtain $u^\ast pu \leq p$ as well. Conjugating by $u$, we have $p = u(u^\ast pu)u^\ast \leq upu^\ast$. Combining the two inequalities, we have $p = upu^\ast$.
For the second question, saying $\tau$ is faithful on $\mathscr{M}(1 - p)$ is just how the definition is written down: we say a semifinite normal weight $\varphi$ is faithful on a von Neumann algebra $\mathscr{N}$ (note that I’m not saying it’s faithful on $\mathscr{N}_+$) if $\varphi(x) = 0$ implies $x = 0$ for $x \in \mathscr{N}_+$. This is despite that $\varphi$ is only defined on $\mathscr{N}_+$, not on the entirety of $\mathscr{N}$. So, saying $\tau$ is faithful on $\mathscr{M}(1 - p)$ doesn’t really mean it’s defined on the entirety of $\mathscr{M}(1 - p)$, just that it’s defined on its positive cone, that’s all.
The spectral theorem is used here to show it’s faithful. Indeed, suppose $x \in \mathscr{M}_+(1 - p)$ and $\tau(x) = 0$. We need to show $x = 0$. Suppose not. Then by spectral theorem, $x \geq \epsilon q$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and nonzero projection $q$. Of course, since $x \in \mathscr{M}_+(1 - p)$, we have $q \leq 1 - p$. On the other hand, $\tau(q) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \tau(x) = 0$, so $q \in \{e: \tau(e) = 0\}$. As $p$ is the supremum of the latter set, $q \leq p$. Thus, $q$ is bounded above by both $p$ and $1 - p$, so $q = 0$, a contradiction. This shows we must have $x = 0$.

Thanks. One last thing that I am a bit confused is that where did they need that the set ${e : \tau(e)=0}$ is upward directed (which I assume is that for any two elements there is a third one which dominates both of them)? I mean, we can take $\vee$ for any set of projections ${f_i}{i\in I},$ which is by definition the projection onto the $\overline{\cup{i} f_i\mathcal{H}}$.

@sigma That is used to show $\tau(p) = 0$. Since ${e: \tau(e) = 0}$ is upward directed, $p = \vee{e: \tau(e) = 0}$ is a strong limit of $e$ with $\tau(e) = 0$, so normality of $\tau$ then implies $\tau(p) = 0$.

still I'm not getting. For an arbitrary family of projections ${f_i}{i\in I}$ we can see that the finite unions $f_J:=\vee{i\in J} f_i$'s ($J\subset I$ finite) form an increasing family of projections such that $\vee_J f_J = \vee_i f_i$. Thus $f_J \to \vee_i f_i$ in sot. Now if $\forall i, \tau(f_i) = 0$ then we also have $\tau(f_J)\le \sum_J \tau(f_i) = 0$. Then by normality $\tau(\vee f_i) = \tau(\lim_J f_J) = \lim_J \tau(f_J)=0$. Isn't this right? Here we choose an arbitrary family of projections of trace zero.

I want to say that for an arbitrary family of projections ${f_i}$ and a normal trace $\tau$ we have: $$\tau(\vee f_i) \le \sum_i \tau(f_i)$$. Here we don't need that the family is 'upward directed'. right? If this is so then where exactly they needed that condition?

@sigma These are all correct - you just combined the two steps (proving the family is upward directed and showing the supremum has trace zero) into one step, while Takesaki presented it as two steps, that’s all. (The fact that the set is upward directed exactly follows from what you noticed, namely, for a finite set $J$, $\vee_{j \in J} f_j$ has trace zero if all $f_j$ have trace zero - upward directed means exactly that for finitely many elements in the set, namely those $f_j$, there is an element greater than or equal to all of them, namely $\vee_{j \in J} f_j$.)

I got it. Thanks!
